# How to loop through a csv file of links to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup and requests and not get requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema?

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I'm quite new to coding in general and thankful for any support from the community!

**What I want to do:**
I have a csv file with links that lead to various products of which I'd like to get the product title and write it back to the same or another csv file (doesn't really matter). To do that, I've tried to import the csv file (which works fine), write each row to a list (which works as well) and then select every value in the list to extract the product title.

**What my problem is:**
The scraping of a single link works, so the problem lies within the list, loop, request combination I guess. If I run the following code I get the error requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

f = open('three_links.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
links = []

for row in reader:
    links.append(row)

for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    title = print(soup.find(class_='sidebar-product-name').text.replace("\n","").replace(" ",""))
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you show how your csv file is written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that each row read from the csv file is a list, and so

```
response = requests.get(link)
```

is actually something like

```
response = requests.get(['https://www.example.com', 'something', 'something else'])
```

You could do this instead (assuming the link is in the first column in the csv:

```
response = requests.get(link[0])
```